# Plot a line over a 2D histogram python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to, for simplicity's sake, plot a line over a 2D histogram, with both the line and the histogram points referring to latitude/longitude coordinates.

Here's an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = np.random.rand(10,10)
longs = [100,101]
lats = [45,46]
x = np.linspace(100,100)
y = np.linspace(45,46)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img,extent=[longs[0],longs[1],lats[0],lats[1]])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, however you cannot see the line for 2 reasons.

1) Your x axis limits are 100 and 101, and you are trying to plot the vertical line at x=100.

2) The default color of the line might make it hard to see

By changing x to 100.5 using

```
x = np.linspace(100.5,100.5)
```

and changing the color of the line to black

```
plt.plot(x, y, color="k")
```

The plot becomes

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I was trying to plot a diagonal line which goes from bottom right to top left, but I've changed the colour of the line and it now appears to work!